# MVC3 & StructureMap, injecting concrete class based on the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

Say several of my controllers constructors take an interface - IPetInterface
There are 3 concrete implementations of IPetInterface.

How would you configure StructureMap to supply one of the concrete implementations based on the controller that needs it.

crude example ....

```
class DogStuff: IPetInterface{}

class CatStuff: IPetInterface{}

class GiraffeStuff: IPetInterface{}

class DogController : Controller
{
    DogController(IPetInterface petStuff)

    // some other stuff that is very unique to dogs
}

class CatController : Controller
{
    CatController(IPetInterface petStuff)

    // some other stuff that is very unquie to cats
}
```

Comment: While I'm sure it can be done with StructureMap (I'm more of a Unity guy myself, so I'm not sure exactly how to do it with StructureMap) are you sure your design is correct? Based on your description, it seems like the interface may be _too_ generic....

Comment: @BFree: It possibly is too generic. Currently I have Separate interfaces for each 'pet' but they are identical so I am wondering if this is possible/worth while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the classes and interfaces provided in the question, this registration would do:

```
For<DogController>().Use<DogController>()
  .Ctor<IPetInterface>("petStuff").Is<DogStuff>();
For<CatController>().Use<CatController>()
  .Ctor<IPetInterface>("petStuff").Is<CatStuff>();
For<GiraffeController>().Use<GiraffeController>()
  .Ctor<IPetInterface>("petStuff").Is<GiraffeStuff>();
```

If this grows beyond 3 registrations with the same pattern I would look into using a convention based registration instead that would automatically register a corresponding "stuff" for each controller based on the naming. This could be achieved [using an IRegistrationConvention](http://www.theabsentmindedcoder.com/2010/05/structure-map-26-using-conventions.html).

Comment: Thanks, just the sort of info I was after!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Stuff<T> : IPetInterface<T> where T : IPet { ... }

interface IPetInterface<T> where T : IPet { ... }

abstract class PetController<T> : Controller where T : IPet
{
    protected PetController<T>(IPetInterface<T> stuff)
    { ... }
}

class CatController : PetController<Cat>
{
    public CatController(IPetInterface<Cat> stuff) : base(stuff) {}

    ...
}

class DogController : PetController<Dog> { ... }
```